# Lumen 5.5: Why are models not in the container?

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container, lumen

According to the [Lumen 5.4 to 5.5 Upgrade Guide](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0), in Lumen 5.5, the service container (which is the `Laravel\Lumen\Application` instance itself) implements the Container interface to follow [PSR-11](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/).

I'm a little confused how automatic resolving works in Lumen and Laravel. I would expect this to echo `"yes"`, but it echoes `"no"`:

```
// File /routes/web.php

$router->get('/', function (App\User $user) {
    return app()->has(App\User::class) ? 'yes' : 'no';
});
```

I'm putting `App\User $user` parameter there just to make sure it's properly loaded, and it is. If auto-resolver is not based on the container, how is it working then?

Comment: You are confusing container and composer. The former is responsible to instantiate objects, the later is to resolve class names and autoload classes.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm talking about this Laravel's auto-resolver, which is not standard way of loading classes.

Comment: Could you provide any reference? If I get https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php#L24 right it uses composer's autoloader to resolve class names

Comment: Yes it does, but autoloading has nothing to do with my question. I'm talking about the process that takes place before autoloading, which is trying to load a class from unused and typehinted parameters.

Comment: router just instantiates a class to pass it to the controller. It does not put it to the container, and I don't see any reason why it possibly should do that.

Comment: I thought that type-hinting an interface that way will use the container to resolve the parameter passed that way. That would make sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: It does, if the the class was previously added to the container, but it does not add it to the container by itself.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. My current understanding of what's going on with these "magic" parameters is: it tries to lookup in the container and return whatever is there. If there's nothing for the particular key, it tries to instantiate like `new Foo()`, without any constructor's parameters. But the type-hint still needs to be valid class/interface/trait. It would be quite cool (but maybe confusing) to be able to type-hint any Container's key that way (and not possible to type-hint those with special characters). Please tell me if I'm correct on all of my points :)

Comment: Almost. It's just other way round - first check if the object comes from the request and create an instance, otherwise try to load it from the container: https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php#L76. I believe the reason for that is quite obvious - if you have 2 models of the same class, like `/link/userId1/userId2` you need 2 different users, not the same one loaded from the container.

Comment: That's interesting, because I did a test. I put `App\User` to the container and  what I got after type-hinting, is the instance from the container, not the `new User`. Your example with `/userId1/userId2` is something else I think - it's auto-resolving models by ID, which is different story. What do you think?

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed. Wrong example. And yes, if you put an instance to the container, all `make($classname)` invocations return that very same instance. Otherwise the container creates a new instance every time without memoizing it. In the second case the role of the container is to resolve dependencies only. Makes sense?

Comment: Just to make it crystal clear your `app()->has()` checks if there is an instance stored in the container, not that the container once instantiated the class.

Comment: Yes, it is crystal clear for me :) Thanks, I will do more experiments and ask if I have any more doubts.